# Identifying a trend in C - Micro controller sampling

Tags: c, microcontroller, sampling

I'm working on an MC68HC11 Microcontroller and have an analogue voltage signal going in that I have sampled. The scenario is a weighing machine, the large peaks are when the object hits the sensor and then it stabilises (which are the samples I want) and then peaks again before the object roles off.

The problem I'm having is figuring out a way for the program to detect this stable point and average it to produce an overall weight but can't figure out how :/. One way I have thought about doing is comparing previous values to see if there is not a large difference between them but I haven't had any success. Below is the **C** code that I am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <iof1.h>

void main(void)
{
/* PORTA, DDRA, DDRG etc... are LEDs and switch ports */

unsigned char *paddr, *adctl, *adr1;
unsigned short i = 0;
unsigned short k = 0;
unsigned char switched = 1; /* is char the smallest data type? */

unsigned char data[2000];

DDRA = 0x00; /* All in */
DDRG = 0xff;
adctl = (unsigned char*) 0x30;
adr1 = (unsigned char*) 0x31;

*adctl = 0x20; /* single continuos scan */

while(1)
{
    if(*adr1 > 40)
    {
        if(PORTA == 128) /* Debugging switch */
        {
            PORTG = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTG = 0;      
        } 
        if(i < 2000)
        {
            while(((*adctl) & 0x80) == 0x00);
            {
                data[i] = *adr1;
            } 
                            /* if(i > 10 && (data[(i-10)] - data[i]) < 20) */
            i++;
        } 
        if(PORTA == switched)
        {   
            PORTG = 31;
            /* Print a delimeter so teemtalk can send to excel */
            for(k=0;k<2000;k++)
            {
                printf("%d,",data[k]);
            }
            if(switched == 1) /*bitwise manipulation more efficient? */
            {
                switched = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                switched = 1;
            }
            PORTG = 0;
        }
        if(i >= 2000)
        {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Look forward to hearing any suggestions :)

(The graph below shows how these values look, the red box is the area I would like to identify.

[image: results]

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question, really.  This is more of a math question--doesn't matter what language you're using, does it?

Comment: true but I don't know of a maths forum :P

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you sample sequence has glitches (short lived transients) try to improve the hardware ie change layout, add decoupling, add filtering etc.

If that approach fails, then a median filter [1] of say five places long, which takes the last five samples, sorts them and outputs the middle one, so two samples of the transient have no effect on it's output. (seven places ...three transient)

Then a computationally efficient exponential averaging lowpass filter [2]

```
                     y(n) = y(n–1) + alpha[x(n) – y(n–1)]
```

choosing alpha (1/2^n, division with right shifts) to yield a time constant [3] of less than the underlying response (~50samples),  but still filter out the noise. Increasing the effective fractional bits will avoid the quantizing issues.

With this improved sample sequence, thresholds and cycle count, can be applied to detect quiescent durations.

Additionally if the end of the quiescent period is always followed by a large, abrupt change then using a sample delay "array", enables the detection of the abrupt change but still have available the last of the quiescent samples for logging.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter

[2] http://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/72.php

[3] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constant

Note
Adding code for the above filtering operations will lower the maximum possible sample rate but printf can be substituted for something faster.

Answer (score 1):

Continusously store the current value and the delta from the previous value.
Note when the delta is decreasing as the start of weight application to the scale
Note when the delta is increasing as the end of weight application to the scale
Take the X number of values with the small delta and average them

BTW, I'm sure this has been done 1M times before, I'm thinking that a search for `scale PID` or `weight PID` would find a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget using ___delay_ms(XX) function somewhere between the reading values, if you will compare with the previous one. The difference in each step will be obviously small, if the code loop continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your nice graphs, I would say you should look only for the falling edge, it is much consistent than leading edge.

In other words, let the samples accumulate, calculate the running average all the time with predefined window size, remember the deviation of the previous values just for reference, check for a large negative bump in your values (like absolute value ten times smaller then current running average), your running average is your value. You could go back a little bit (disregarding last few values in your average, and recalculate) to compensate for small positive bump visible in your picture before each negative bump...No need for heavy math here, you could not model the reality better then your picture has shown, just make sure that your code detect the end of each and every sample. You have to be fast enough with sample to make sure no negative bump was missed (or you will have big time error in your data averaging).

And you don't need that large arrays, running average is better based on smaller window size, smaller residual error in your case when you detect the negative bump.